# Rails activerecord query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have two models:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :payments_received 
end

class PaymentReceived < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :invoice
end
```

I need to write a query to find invoices that have either no payments_received or the sum of the payments_received.amount is less than the invoice.amount

I am able to find invoices with no payments_received:

```
@invoices = Invoice.includes(:payments_received).where( :payments_received => { :invoice_id => nil } )
```

But I need to find invoices where the sum of all of its associated payments_received is less than invoice.amount.

This is a class method that accomplishes what I need, but I'd like to do this without pulling all of the invoices out of the database and iterating through each one of them.

```
def self.unpaid
  unpaid_invoices = []
  total_payments = 0
  invoices = Invoice.all
  invoices.each do |invoice|
    if invoice.payments_received.empty?
      unpaid_invoices << invoice
    else
      invoice.payments_received.each do |payment_received|
        total_payments += payment_received.amount
      end
      if total_payments < invoice.amount
        unpaid_invoices << invoice
      end
    end
  end
  unpaid_invoices
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you can chain where clauses:

```
@invoices = Invoice.includes(:payments_received).where( :payments_received => { :invoice_id => nil } ).where("payments_received.amount > ?", amount)
```

try writing them both individually and after you're getting what you want to return chain the query together.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you want something like this.

```
@invoices.collect do |invoice|
  invoice.payments_received.pluck(:amount).sum < invoice.amount ? invoice : next
end.compact
```

Comment: I like this code @Ahsan Ellahi, but I'm looking for a way to accomplish this without pulling all of the invoices out of the database and iterating through each one of them.